# Representations of the set of all mappings

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Assume that we have a (compact) group $(G, \cdot)$, which comes with a representation $\rho \colon G \rightarrow \text{GL}(V)$.

Let $X$ be a set and denote by $G^X$ the set of all mappings from $X$ to $G$, i.e.,
$$
G^X = \operatorname{Maps}(X,G) = \{ f \colon X \to G \}.
$$

This can be equipped with a group structure induced by $G$ under the "point-wise" operation
$$
(f \star g)(x) = f(x) \cdot g(x), \quad \text{where $x \in X$}.
$$

My question is the following: Can we (in general) also "induce" a representation
$$
\chi \colon G^X \to \operatorname{GL}(V)
$$
from the representation $\rho \colon G \to \operatorname{GL}(V)$?

My guess is *no*, precisely because the operation on $G^X$ is defined pointwise, but perhaps I am missing something? Is there any good literature on this?

Comment: What about $\chi(f):=\rho(f(x_0))$?

Comment: But then $\chi : G^X \rightarrow \text{Rep}(G)$? That is, $\chi (f) = \rho (f)(\cdot )$ acts (depends) on the point $x_0 \in X$?

Comment: $\chi (f) = \rho (f)(\cdot )$ makes no sense. What I proposed is a representation $\chi:G^X\to\operatorname{GL}(V),$ given a representation $\rho:G\to\operatorname{GL}(V)$ and an element $x_0\in X.$